# Adding bullet points in a table with razor and css

Tags: css, html, razor

I am trying to add bullet points to the date in my table, but somehow I can't manage it.. 
The code is as followed:

```
<tbody>

        @foreach (LearningGoal Item in goals) {

            <tr>

                <td>@Item.description</td>

            </tr>

        }
    </tbody>
```

I want to add a bulletpoint for each description item

Answer (score 2):

Could you just use

```
    @foreach (LearningGoal Item in goals) {

        <tr>

            <td>&bull; @Item.description</td>

        </tr>

    }
</tbody>
```

`&bull;` looks like • and is an html bullet point

Otherwise, I'd recommend using list elements (`<li>` tags) and then looking at the `list-style` css property.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a out of the box `<ul>` (unordered list)?

```
<ul>
  @foreach (LearningGoal Item in goals) 
  {
    <li>
      @Item.description
    </li>
  }
</ul>
```

If you want numbers instead of bulletpoints, just use a ordered list `<ol>` instead of `<ul>`

Comment: This gives me the error: Cannot nest <ul> inside element tbody

Comment: Dont use a table for this. Either a list or a data definition.